# Plotly Dash figure only renders LaTeX with MathJax v2, markdown only renders LaTeX with MathJax v3

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cdn, mathjax

Context: developing scientific dashboard and need `LaTeX` to render in both graphs and text.

Summary of the problem:

- `dcc.Markdown` only works with MathJax v3.2 and not v2 (see [dash documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/markdown))
- `dcc.Figure` only works with MathJax v2 and not v3.2. (I don't know why)

Here are the versions of the libraries if relevant:

```
>>> plotly.__version__
'5.11.0'
>>> dash.__version__
'2.7.0'
```

According to the [Plotly Documentation](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.8.0), better support for MathJax v3 should already exist for version 5.8.0.

The CDNs I have tried:

```
from dash import Dash

# v2
MATHJAX_CDN = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"

# v3
MATHJAX_CDN = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.0/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js'

app = Dash(__name__, external_scripts=[MATHJAX_CDN])
```

As mentioned above, with v2: `dcc.Figure` renders `LaTeX` with `mathjax=True`. `dcc.Markdown` does not.

With v3: `dcc.Markdown` renders `LaTeX` with `mathjax=True`. `dcc.Figure` does not.

How do I reconcile this issue?

- Is there a CDN link I can use for which BOTH figures AND markdown will render LaTeX?
- Is the reason why it's not working something to do with `es5` or `AM_CHTML` which are unique to each imported CDN?

---

Edit:

I have also tried creating a fresh environment with up-to-date versions of both `plotly` (5.13.1) and `dash` (2.9.0). Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a simple matter of just NOT manually loading a `MATHJAX_CDN` into `external_scripts` at all.

So instead of this:

```
from dash import Dash

# v2
MATHJAX_CDN = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"

# v3
MATHJAX_CDN = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.0/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js'

app = Dash(__name__, external_scripts=[MATHJAX_CDN])
```

Do this instead:

```
from dash import Dash

app = Dash(__name__)
```

and just add `mathjax=True` to `dcc.Figure` and `dcc.Markdown` as normal.

Keeping in mind I did this with the newer fresh python environment; haven't checked this for the older versions I'd previously specified.

[Source here](https://community.plotly.com/t/mathjax-latex-in-dash/6653/24)